# Intel Xeon E5-2698 v3 with quad memory channels, what should be the real expected memory bandwidth?

Tags: memory, cpu, bandwidth

I suppose this question could be made more general to cover all cpus that make use of multi-channel memory, but what I'm trying to determine is how exactly the multi-channeling is done.

I've heard analogies to RAID 0, but is this still accurate in the case of DDR 4?

If the scaling is done as well as the marketing material makes it seem, you should be able to take a chunk of memory that's evenly divisible by the number of channels you have and enjoy the maximum bandwidth of all channels.

What I'm led to understand, however, is that memory is generally addressed contiguously (let's say you're building a program in C from the ground up) and when that program runs, it'll run in at least a somewhat grouped chunk of memory, not strewn all over the place.

Unless I'm somehow manually making a map of the system memory in my program, and manually storing data in the address spaces of different channels, what guarantee do I have I'm actually seeing the aggregate bandwidth of all of my channels?

Comment: The bandwidth is dependant on the chipset being used. What guarantee you have is that, the specification of the chipset on the motherboarrd, which is what specifiies the bandwidth of the memory.

Comment: Well in my case, I should be seeing roughly 120GB/s from all channels.  Oddly, dd reports that I'm lucky to get about 2.4GB/s.  I'm using /dev/zero to write some data to a ramdisk and the results are confusingly bad.

Comment: You are not going to get 120GB/sec from your memory.  Your expectations of 120GB/sec is not realistic.  The specifications for your CPU indicate the max bandwidth, for the CPU itself, is 68 GB/s.

Comment: Ah yes, the single socket should pull 68, but we have dual sockets, but I see now that filesystem overhead ruins memory benchmarking done with dd here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341430/why-writing-speed-of-ram-is-coming-far-less-than-what-is-mentioned-on-it

Comment: In order to say if the analogies to RAID 0 to a multi-channel memory system is accurate I would have to read the analogie myself. can you provide it?